# Scroll does not work in kivy Layout of buttons

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
<Builder_Screen>
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y:True
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text:"Heading"
                size_hint_x: .25
                size_hint_y: .25
                text_size: self.size
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                pos: 0,10
            Button:
                text:"Paragraph"
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                size_hint_x: .25
                size_hint_y: .25
                pos: (0,self.height)
```

I have some buttons like these with positions like pos: 0, self.height*2 , self.height*3 etc.
But, the scroll layout does not work as intended.
Can you help me regarding that!...

Comment: On first sight, I think there is nothing wrong with your code. Scrolling on some platforms only works when the window is not big enough to show the content. What happens if you add more buttons (or widgets) and test it again?

Comment: I added about 18 Buttons but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position), regarding the child of a `ScrollView`:

> By default, the size_hint is (1, 1), so the content size will fit your
> ScrollView exactly (you will have nothing to scroll). You must
> deactivate at least one of the size_hint instructions (x or y) of the
> child to enable scrolling.

So, you probably need to set `size_hint_y: None` for your `FloatLayout`. That will cause further problems, because you have `size_hint_y` values for your `Buttons`. You can set the heights of your `Buttons` and eliminate the `size_hint_y` values. Another approach would be to use a `GridLayout`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

kv = '''
<Builder_Screen>
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y:True
        effect_cls: 'ScrollEffect'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: 5
            spacing: 5
            Button:
                text:"Heading1"
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 48
            Button:
                text:"Paragraph1"
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 48
            Button:
                text:"Heading2"
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 48
            Button:
                text:"Paragraph2"
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 48
            Button:
                text:"Heading3"
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 48
            Button:
                text:"Paragraph3"
                halign:"center"
                valign:"center"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 48
'''

class Builder_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Builder_Screen()

TestApp().run()
```

Note that every `Button` has an explicit `height`. That is required if you use `height: self.minimum_height` for their container.

Comment: The output is  as shown in the link below 

[link] (https://pasteboard.co/JQjZUhK.png) 

The desired output is Something like a TABLE which is scrollable..... C

Comment: Try using a `GridLayout` instead of  `BoxLayout`.

Comment: Ok i would, can you plz help in how to make the buttons in grid layout?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zJi17CTM
Above is the code
What should i do if i need a scroll and i need 2 rows and the buttons must cover the coloumn width?

Comment: You need to read the documentation more carefully. The `orientation: "lr-tb"` property is not part of `GridLayout`. See my updated answer above.