# Why my image is on the toolbar not below it in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, scrollview, kivymd

I can't just figure it out why my image is on the toolbar not below it.
I have tried many attempts like changing the height etc etc but it didn't worked for me.
Can anyone help me out to get the right code for this one please
Piece of my code :

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (360 , 640)
kv = '''
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
ScreenManager:
    Second:
<Second>:
    name: 'second'
    MDToolbar:
        id :toolbar
        title: "..."
        elevation: 10
        specific_text_color: get_color_from_hex('#FCF6F5FF')
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex('#822057FF')
    ScrollView:
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1,None
            adaptive_height: True
            height: root.height-toolbar.height
            orientation:'vertical'
            AsyncImage:
                source: 'national.jpg'
            MDLabel:
                halign:'center'
                md_bg_color:get_color_from_hex('#FCF6F5FF')
                text: 'National Digital Library of India (NDLI) is a virtual repository of learning resources which is not just a repository with search/browse facilities but provides a host of services for the learner community. It is sponsored and mentored by Ministry of Education, Government of India, through its National Mission on Education through Information and Communication Technology (NMEICT). Filtered and federated searching is employed to facilitate focused searching so that learners can find the right resource with least effort and in minimum time. NDLI provides user group-specific services such as Examination Preparatory for School and College students and job aspirants. '
'''
class Second(Screen):
    pass
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
Test().run()
```

Thanks for Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find a solution using `Layouts` as shown in below code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (360, 640)
kv = '''
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
ScreenManager:
    Second:
<Second>:
    name: 'second'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id :toolbar
            title: "..."
            elevation: 10
            specific_text_color: get_color_from_hex('#FCF6F5FF')
            pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
            md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex('#822057FF')
        ScrollView:
            MDBoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1,None
                adaptive_height: True
                height: 500
                orientation:'vertical'
                AsyncImage:
                    source: 'national.jpg'
                MDLabel:
                    halign:'center'
                    md_bg_color:get_color_from_hex('#FCF6F5FF')
                    text: 'National Digital Library of India (NDLI) is a virtual repository of learning resources which is not just a repository with search/browse facilities but provides a host of services for the learner community. It is sponsored and mentored by Ministry of Education, Government of India, through its National Mission on Education through Information and Communication Technology (NMEICT). Filtered and federated searching is employed to facilitate focused searching so that learners can find the right resource with least effort and in minimum time. NDLI provides user group-specific services such as Examination Preparatory for School and College students and job aspirants. '
'''


class Second(Screen):
    pass


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)


Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollView needs its height calculated by using root.height - toolbar.height then it will correctly show up. I also added Screen: under the second screen.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (360 , 640)
kv = '''
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
ScreenManager:
    Second:
<Second>:
    name: 'second'
    Screen:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id :toolbar
            title: "..."
            elevation: 10
            specific_text_color: get_color_from_hex('#FCF6F5FF')
            pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
            md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex('#822057FF')
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: root.height - toolbar.height
            MDBoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1,None
                adaptive_height: True
                height: root.height-toolbar.height
                orientation:'vertical'
                AsyncImage:
                    source: 'national.jpg'
                MDLabel:
                    halign:'center'
                    md_bg_color:get_color_from_hex('#FCF6F5FF')
                    text: 'National Digital Library of India (NDLI) is a virtual repository of learning resources which is not just a repository with search/browse facilities but provides a host of services for the learner community. It is sponsored and mentored by Ministry of Education, Government of India, through its National Mission on Education through Information and Communication Technology (NMEICT). Filtered and federated searching is employed to facilitate focused searching so that learners can find the right resource with least effort and in minimum time. NDLI provides user group-specific services such as Examination Preparatory for School and College students and job aspirants. '
'''
class Second(Screen):
    pass
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
Test().run()
```

Comment: But it's not scrolling..

Comment: Try to use GridLayout insted of BoxLayout

refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400801/scroll-does-not-work-in-kivy-layout-of-buttons)

Comment: didn't work for me @Devam